# How to create DataFrame with 100 values consisting of 10 elementary numbers in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, random

I need to create Data Frame in Python Pandas with 100 rows with random values consisting of 10 elementary numbers.
So as a result I need something like below "col1" has to be as date type string:

```
col1
---------
1233459857
8463746781
9084756289
...
```

How can I do that in python pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that values beginning with one or more zeros are properly formatted, we can create values of data type string with zero padding to 10 places:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(rng.integers(0, 10**10, size=100)).apply(lambda n: f'{n:0>10}'), columns=['col1'])
```

Output:

```
          col1
0   9448137321
1   9080789825
2   0131300041
3   6795692128
4   5236197395
..         ...
95  0541351442
96  6920748551
97  9563382744
98  2385042247
99  3736754262
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.random.Generator.integers` to create the integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": np.random.default_rng().integers(1000000000, 10000000000, 100)})
print(df)

col1
0   7612431035
1   4173337084
2   5208961112
3   4717726170
4   8300616999
..         ...
95  4685852377
96  2047960728
97  2354643233
98  6465408928
99  7202650975

[100 rows x 1 columns]
```